# Is using AWS S3 with AWS EC2 necessary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have been using EC2 for several months now for my mobile application, and I have come to a point where I would like to make the server as great as I can...

I have just been using EC2 and uploading images/video etc to it, now after 6-8 of research, I am quite confused!

Should I be using S3 with EC2 or maybe EBS with EC2? I am not sure. Have I been doing it completely wrong the whole time by just uploading file to the EC2 server?

I have PhpMyAdmin installed on my instance to monitor the stuff...

Now I am not completely sure this question should be asked here or not, but I would love if someone could just help me understand a little more of what it is I am doing! As I am now completely confused!!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Amazon EC2** is a virtual computer that can run whatever software you wish. For example, you could run an Apache web server with PHP so that your website can run custom logic.

**Amazon S3** is an object storage service that can store as much data as you like, with the optional ability to *serve* that content to the Internet (given appropriate security settings that make the data accessible).

So, Amazon S3 can also act as a web server, but without the logic layer -- it can only serve static content.

Some people **combine the two services**:

- Serve static content from Amazon S3 (eg pictures, style sheets, documents)
- Serve web pages and perform logic on Amazon EC2 (eg PHP scripts, user authentication, personalization)
- Multiple EC2 instances can access data stored in S3 -- think of it like a Key/Value Store like a database. This helps to scale services without having to replicate data.
- Use EBS to store the operating system and application, but S3 or a database to store data.

The bottom line is that it all depends on the needs of your particular application, but do think about how you can take advantage of S3 for storage and service static assets.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. It already is a little clearer to me. So from what I understand for an application like Instagram for example, you would use EC2 for the logic and then S3 for storing all the images and videos uploaded by the users? I don't fully understand the last bullet point 'Use EBS to store the operating....' but I shall do some more research today! Thanks a lot yet again, if you could confirm my question regarding the 'Instagram application' that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you are correct! As for EBS, a computer expects to have a local disk to boot the operating system, run applications, store temporary data, etc. EBS meets that need. However, try to avoid storing "data" on the local disk because it is only accessible to that one machine (not good for scaling) and would need a backup strategy.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! But after another day of research I think I should possibly go for a simpler solution like Haruko or AWS Lambda? whats your opinion on Lambda?

Comment: If you have another question, please start another Question. However, please note that StackOverflow is primarily for coding problems, not for gathering general opinions.